# Creating a workable jar

Tags: java, executable-jar, manifest.mf

Ok, this is round two of my problem.
I have created a simple program in notepad and saved it as a (Blocktestgui.java)java file.
I compile with the command javac Blocktestgui.java and get (Blocktestgui.class)
I created a text manifest file (see below) and saved it as manifest.mf
I then run the command `jar cvf bg.jar Blocktestgui.class manifest.mf` and get (bg.jar)

This is my java file:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Blocktestgui {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String firstNumber, secondNumber;
    double number1, number2, sum;

    firstNumber=JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter wall length in decimal feet:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    secondNumber=JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter wall height in decimal feet:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    number1=Double.parseDouble (firstNumber);
    number2=Double.parseDouble (secondNumber);

    sum = (number1*number2) / 0.88;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Total Blocks are " + sum,"Results",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    System.exit (0);
    }
}
```

This is my manifest.mf before creating the jar:

```
Main-Class: Blocktestgui
```

When I extract the contents of the jar I get a folder and two files

**Folder>--META-INF <--contains MANIFEST.MF<-- This file does not contain the line Main-Class: Blocktestgui**

**File>--Blocktestgui.class**

**File>--manifest.mf<--All this file says is Main-Class: Blocktestgui**

```
TestFolder/
    |- META-INF/
        |- MANIFEST.MF (This file does not contain the line Main-Class: Blocktestgui)
    |- Blocktestgui.class
    |- manifest.mf (This file says is Main-Class: Blocktestgui)
```

When I run the jar file in console with java -jar bg.jar it gives me an error of "no main manifest attribute, in bg.jar"

What am I messing up on ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the manifest info separately, not simply as one of the files to be included:

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jar.html):

```
jar c[v0Mmfe] [manifest] [jarfile] [entrypoint] [-C dir] inputfiles [-Joption]
```

In your case:

```
jar cvmf manifest.mf bg.jar Blockingtestgui.class
```

Or, more simply, without a specific manifest file:

```
jar cvfe bg.jar Blockingtestgui.class Blockingtestgui.class
```

The first `Blockingtestgui.class` specifies the entry point, the second the files to be included.  Note, the order of flags matters here; the `m`, `f`, and `e` information should appear in the order the flags are specified.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Although I still need to re-read your post to understand what is actually working here, the first line worked like a charm. 
`jar cvmf manifest.mf bg.jar Blocktestgui.class`

I am just starting out and some of these concepts are difficult.  I am reading through a beginning java book and after a chapter on JOptionPanes I decided to try my own and I wanted a working jar file and then an exe, just to see if I could do it.  Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a build tool to create a jar file, rather than trying to create one yourself.

[Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) is commonly used to build jar files.

[Here are instructions for installing Ant on Windows.](https://blogs.oracle.com/rajeshthekkadath/entry/installing_ant_on_windows)

[Here's a tutorial for writing an Ant build.xml file for your project.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your single line in the manifest.mf file ends with a new line charachter.